# How to query through an excel document column using cfspreadsheet in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfspreadsheet

I need to do some validation on an excel spreadsheet before I upload to database.

How do I query through an excel document column using cfspreadsheet in ColdFusion?

I need to verify that specific columns don't have any null values in any of their rows.
I have the number of rows in a cold Fusion variable and the number of columns will always be the same.

Thus far, I've been able to figure out the following (below) about cfspreadsheet.

I could put the code below inside a `<cfloop>` and increment the column and rows with cfif statements to skip the columns I don't want to check. 
The loop would end with the total numberOfRows CF variable that I have, but I imagine there's a better way to do this using a query.

Can I do this in a query? If so, how?

```
<cfspreadsheet
  action="read" 
  format = "html"
  src="#SESSION.theFile#"
  name= "test"
  rows = "3"
  columns = "6"
  >


<cfoutput>
   #test#
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: CFSpreadsheet can return the results in several format. To work with a query object, you need to use the `query` attribute, not `format=html`. Once you have a query, you can filter it using a [QoQ](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff9.html).

Comment: Once I have used the query attribute, how do I execute a query on that query variable?

Comment: Use a QoQ. See the previous link. Though `cfdump` the query variable first to see and understand the query columns you can access.

Comment: I see the dump file with all the columns.

Comment: @Leigh please place this as an answer, so I can mark it answered.

Comment: I have a followup question on QoQ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21803872/query-of-queries-failing-in-coldfusion-10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(From comments...)

CFSpreadsheet can return the results in several format. To work with a query object, you need to use the `query` attribute, not `format=html`. Once you have a query, you can filter it using a [QoQ](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e4fd-7ff9.html). CFDump the query variable first to see and understand the query columns you can access.

Answer (score 0):

You can do things like

```
<cfspreadsheet action="read" src="#theFile#" sheetname="courses" 
    name="spreadsheetData"> 
<cfdump var="#speadsheetData#">
```

Adapted from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec17cba-7f87.html